# Connect to external SQL Server database from Docker container (SSL error)

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, networking

How can I connect with external database available by IP `123.123.123.123,2401` (ip is random) from my Docker container. My connection string below, I do have the `TrustServerCertificate=True` option which was recommended to resolve that problem:

```
server=123.123.123.123,2401; database=base_prod; User=XXX; Password=XXX; Application Name=test_PROD; TrustServerCertificate=True
```

While running container I get error

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

In my Dockerfile I expose 2401 port and map it on docker run command -p 2401:2401.

```
docker run -i --network host -p 5000:5000 -p 2401:2401 test-api-db
```

In log I see, it perfectly works outside container

```
SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the sqlserver from your app without docker?

Comment: yes, as host system I have Win11. Container is build on mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 image as base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution: my external database doesn't support TLS1.2 for connection.

If you can not affect on your database provider you can allow to auth by TLS1.0. You can use **SED** command to modify configuration of openssl in image

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base

RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.2/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.2/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

I hope it would help someone